# Texto difícil de entender después de editar una pregunta

Tags: soporte, traducciones, ediciones-sugeridas

No se si me he explicado bien en la pregunta. Sucede que acabo de editar una pregunta y me ha salido un mensaje como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué significa pares? ¿No es mejor poner el texto: `Esta edición será visible solo para ti hasta que sea revisada por un moderador`?.

Comment: Quieres saber [que significa *par*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=par), o como funciona la [revisión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review) de ediciones?

Comment: Ninguna de las 2. Me refiero a que no es una palabra muy conocida en muchos países de habla hispana. Por eso escribo al final, no sería mejor cambiarla por una palabra más común como `moderador`?

Comment: Ya entiendo. Pero 'moderador' no es correcto. Si 'par' no es buena palabra, será mejor pensar en otra opción.

Comment: Sí, ciertamente es un término algo confuso, pero parece que es el estándar: [Revisión por pares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revisi%C3%B3n_por_pares)

Answer (score 3):

Es que no es necesario que sea revisada por un moderador: cualquier usuario con la suficiente reputación puede aprobar o rechazar la edición. Cuando cierto número de usuarios ha aprobado la edición, esta se considera aceptada.

Comment: Entonces supongo que los administradores de SO quitarán este aviso no?. Y en caso de que se pretenda conservar, no sería mejor cambiar el texto de todas formas?, ya que alguien con poca reputación como yo podría querer editar también.